Question on the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups
This is Lemma 13.9 from the Abstract Algebra textbook by Judson. I am struggling to understand certain steps in the proof.

Lemma 13.9 Let $G$ be a finite abelian p-group and suppose that $g \in G$ has maximal order. Then $G$ is isomorphic to $\langle g\rangle\times H$ for some subgroup $H$ of $G$.

First, we can assume that the order of $G$ is $p^n$. We proof by induction on $n$. If $n=1$ it is trivial. Suppose now that the lemma holds for all integers $k$ such that $1 \leq k <n$ and let $g$ be of maximal order in $G$, such that $|g|=p^m$. Now choose $h$ in $G$ such that $h \notin \langle g\rangle$, where $h$ has the smallest possible order. Then, the book was trying to show that $\langle g\rangle \cap H=\{e\}$. It argues that it is sufficient to show that $|H|=p$. Why is this the case? If $|H|=p$, why is it impossible for $h^q \in \langle g\rangle$, where $q<p$?
Then, since $|h^p|=|h|/p$, the order of $h^p$ is smaller than the order of $h$ and must be in $\langle g\rangle$ by the minimality of $h$. So $h^p=g^r$ for some number $r$. Then the book says $p$ must occur as a factor of $r$, in other words $r=ps$. Why is this the case?
Finally, we are at one point where we proved that $G/H \cong (gH) \times K/H$, for some subgroup $K$ of $G$ containing H. Then the book proved that $\langle g\rangle \cap  H=\{e\}$. I can follow all of that. However, the book then says it follows that $G=\langle g\rangle K$. I am not sure why is this the case. I understand that $K$ contains $H$, and that $H$ and $\langle g\rangle$ are sort of separate, but why can we guarantee that $G=\langle g\rangle K$?

You never say who $H$ is. Is $H$ supposed to be $H=\langle h\rangle$?

The author writes $H = \langle h \rangle$.

Why is it sufficient to prove $|H|=p$?

Then $H$ has no subgroups except for $\{e\}$ and $H$. In particular, $\langle g \rangle \cap H$ is $\{e\}$ or $H$. It cannot be $H$ though, since then $H \subseteq \langle g \rangle$, hence $h \in \langle g \rangle$, a contradiction.

Why is it sufficent to prove $h^p=e$?

This implies that the order of $h$ divides $p$, hence it is $ 1$ or $p$. But $h \neq e$, so the order of $h$ will be $p$, i.e. the order of $H$ will be $p$.

Why must $p$ be a factor of $r$?

If not, $up^m + vr = 1$ for some integers $u,v$, and then you will be able to deduce $ g \in \langle g^r \rangle$, which was excluded before.

Why $G = \langle g \rangle K$?

Let $x \in G$. Since $xH \in G/H = \langle gH \rangle \times K/H$, we can write $x = g^n k h$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $k \in K$ and $h \in H$. Since $H \subseteq K$, this shows $x = g^n k'$ for some $k' \in K$, and we are done.
